# How to convert Map key values into array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps, key, distinct-values

I have a Map that contains keys and their value. I want to convert all keyvalues into an array

```
const gameEvents = new Map([
  [17, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [36, ' Substitution'],
  [47, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [61, ' Substitution'],
  [64, ' Yellow card'],
  [69, ' Red card'],
  [70, ' Substitution'],
  [72, ' Substitution'],
  [76, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [80, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [92, ' Yellow card'],
]);
```

I want that my new array should look like this

```
['⚽ GOAL',' Substitution','⚽ GOAL' ,' Substitution', ' Yellow card', ' Red card', ' Substitution',' Substitution',, '⚽ GOAL', '⚽ GOAL', ' Yellow card']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do

```js
const gameEvents = new Map([
  [17, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [36, ' Substitution'],
  [47, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [61, ' Substitution'],
  [64, ' Yellow card'],
  [69, ' Red card'],
  [70, ' Substitution'],
  [72, ' Substitution'],
  [76, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [80, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [92, ' Yellow card'],
]);

console.log([...gameEvents.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const gameEvents = [
  [17, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [36, ' Substitution'],
  [47, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [61, ' Substitution'],
  [64, ' Yellow card'],
  [69, ' Red card'],
  [70, ' Substitution'],
  [72, ' Substitution'],
  [76, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [80, '⚽ GOAL'],
  [92, ' Yellow card'],
];

console.log(gameEvents.map(x => x[1]))
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: gameEvents.map is not a function

I'm facing the above problem